# Given an empty count matrix and a dictionary that maps customers to lists of purchases, how do I fill the matrix with each purchase?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, matrix

I am stuck on a problem where I am supposed to fill an empty count matrix using a dictionary where the keys are customers and the values are lists of item numbers that represent purchased items.

So my function is called fill_count_matrix() and it takes an empty count matrix (DataFrame) and a dictionary of customer orders. It is supposed to return a matrix where the values are incremented based on the customer purchases. The diagonals (the cells where the row and column values are the same item) are supposed to count the number of customers who bought that item. The off-diagonal cells (where the row and column values are different items) are supposed to count the number of customers who bought both items.

Here is an example of the parameters:

```
#empty count matrix (index and columns are the same list of item numbers):
     971  972  973  974
971    0    0    0    0
972    0    0    0    0
973    0    0    0    0
974    0    0    0    0 

#Dict of customer purchaces: 
{1: ['971', '973'], 2: ['971', '972', '974'], 3: ['971', '974']}
```

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
def fill_count_matrix(c_matrix, p_matrix):
    '''
    '''
    for i, (key, val) in enumerate(p_matrix.items()):
          for row in c_matrix.index:
                for col in c_matrix.columns:
                    if row in val and col in val:
                        c_matrix.loc[row,col] += 1
    return c_matrix
```

Here is the output I get from the parameters above:

```
     971  972  973  974
971    3    1    1    2
972    1    1    0    1
973    1    0    1    0
974    2    1    0    2
```

The error I am getting is coming from an automated test that is testing my code, so I don't know how much help it will be but here it is:

```
FAIL: test_fill_count_matrix (__main__.TestFns)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw1_test.py", line 40, in test_fill_count_matrix
    self.assertIsNone(fill_count_matrix(self.vals_all['empty_count'][i], self.vals_all['purchase'][i]))
AssertionError:      971  972  973  974
971    3    1    1    2
972    1    1    0    1
973    1    0    1    0
974    2    1    0    2 is not None

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This has been stumping me for hours and I'm not sure what is wrong with my function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your test seems to indicate that there is some case where you should return `None`, but you always give the initial `cmatrix` back in return. Do you know in what instances `fill_count_matrix` should return none?

Comment: I am not aware of a time when the function should return None, which makes the test result really confusing.

Comment: Well `self.assertIsNone(` specifically is saying that the result of the return should be None. You might consider reviewing the requirements for your project, or your tests if you've written them yourself.

Comment: After looking at it, the function is actually supposed to change the dataframe in place and return None. Thanks for helping me think about it in that way.

Comment: You might also note that python programs, by default, `return None` if there is no return at all in the function body. Perhaps your program is to have no return statement (making it an implicit "return None")

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without loops. Start from *Series*:

```
s = pd.Series({1: ['971', '973'], 2: ['971', '972', '974'], 3: ['971', '974']})

s.explode().pipe(lambda x: pd.crosstab(x.index, x)).pipe(lambda x: x.T.dot(x))

col_0  971  972  973  974
col_0                    
971      3    1    1    2
972      1    1    0    1
973      1    0    1    0
974      2    1    0    2
```

---

Steps:

1. Flatten series:

```py
fs = s.explode()

fs
1    971
1    973
2    971
2    972
2    974
3    971
3    974
dtype: object
```

2. Calculate the *contingency table* using `crosstab`:

```py
ct = pd.crosstab(fs.index, fs)

ct
col_0  971  972  973  974
row_0                    
1        1    0    1    0
2        1    1    0    1
3        1    0    0    1
```

3. The matrix multiplication of *contingency table* against the transpose of itself gives the coocurrence matrix:

```py
ct.T.dot(ct)

col_0  971  972  973  974
col_0                    
971      3    1    1    2
972      1    1    0    1
973      1    0    1    0
974      2    1    0    2
```